# How to define multiple keys for @CachePut?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

How can I use `@CachePut` on an object, and update a cache by *multiple* properties of it?

Example:
Cached persons are added to `PERSONS` cache every time the 'findOneByFirstnameAndLastname()` method is invoked.

If the `Person` object is persisted, I also want the cache to update the person. But how can I tell `@CachePut` to use both `firstname+lastname` as the key for the `PERSONS` cache? Right now the `save()` method does *not* update the cache...

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    //assume there is only one valid person
    @Cachable("PERSONS")
    Person findOneByFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname);

    //TODO how to update cache by entity.firstname + entity.lastname
    @CachePut("PERSONS")
    @Override
    Person save(Person entity);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use your cache like a database, don't do that :)

Comment: I want to update the database, and also keep the most frequent objects in the `PERSONS` cache (which is backed by a further configured CacheManager, but that's not important for the question). Why shouldn't I do this, to reduce latency and limit query traffic in particular cases...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end I succeeded in using reference to the parameters (`#p1, #2`) during lookip and reference to `#result.*` during persist:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "PERSONS", key = "#p1 + #p2")
Person findByFirstnameAndLastName(String firstname, String lastname);

@CachePut(cacheNames = "PERSONS", key = "#result.firstName + #result.lastName")
Person save(Person person);
```

Yet I don't know why I could not use `#firstname + #lastname` or `#person.firstname + #person.lastname`, but Spring constantly complains about having `null` parameters then. Maybe Spring cannot resolve the parameter names at this stage, whysoever.

Comment: I think the parameter numbers start from 0 as in p0, p1

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue your choice of cache key is a bit naive... firstname + lastname?

Clearly, it is not uncommon for a person's name to change, especially the last name, such as when a person gets married. Her (sometimes his) last name typically changes.

Second, I'd argue this ("*assume there is only one valid person*") is a pretty weak assumption in most cases.

Obviously you are trying to cache a rather typical and common data access operation in your application, like "*look up a person by their first and last name*", that invokes the search operation (query) defined in your SD *Repository*, which is possibly triggered by some CSR when a person calls in for support, perhaps.  However, this is an inappropriate use of caching, at the wrong level of abstraction.

What do you think will happen if your cache key changes?

You essentially have a memory leak since the entry basically becomes unreachable. 
Even if the entry eventually expires or gets evicted, if the expiration or eviction is not performed in a timely manner (subject to memory constraints and load, along with your cache eviction/expiration policies, of course) it is easy to run out of memory.

It is quite common for most caches to cache an entry based on the "hash" of the key.  This turns out to be quite useful in some cache implementations (technically, "*data grids*") where the data is partitioned and balanced across many data nodes in a cluster.  Though, as you probably know, caches are not unlike a `java.util.HashMap`. In fact, many of them do implement the `java.util.Map` or `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap` interface.

This is generally why it is preferable to use a surrogate key in caching rather than a natural key, like a person's name + DOB, or SSN, etc.  A surrogate key is unlikely to ever change and is only meant for internal, referential purposes, especially in the likely hood that the underlying data can and may change, which I'd say in your UC is highly likely.  Also, given the use of "hashing" in most caches, it is the reason why scalar values (e.g `Long`) are used as keys.

Using *natural keys* should only be done with great care and where the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the key have been properly implemented.

Still, if you are dead set on using the "*first + last name*" of a `Person`, you can define a cache key using a [SpEL expression](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions), like so...

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "PERSONS", key = "#firstname + #lastname")
Person findByFirstnameAndLastName(String firstname, String lastname);

@CachePut(cacheNames = "PERSONS", key = "#person.firstName + #person.lastName")
Person save(Person person);
```

> NOTE: alternatively, the `@CachePut` "`key`" could also be defined as "`#result.firstname + #result.lastname`".

Of course, you could simplify this if your `Person` class had a `getName()` method (or a `name` "property"), like so...

```
class Person {

  ...

  String getName() {
    return String.format("%1$s %2$s", getFirstName(), getLastName());
  }
}
```

Then...

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "PERSONS", key = "#firstname + ' ' + #lastname")
Person findByFirstnameAndLastName(String firstname, String lastname);

@CachePut(cacheNames = "PERSONS", key = "#person.name")
Person save(Person person);
```

See [SpEL's mathematical operators](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operators-mathematical), particularly involving String concatenation, for more details.

Also see the [Section on Cache Keys](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key) for more details.

Personally, I recommend a slightly different caching strategy, especially if you are not absolutely certain the data will be used relatively soon, or "frequently".  Many caches keep data around based on frequency of use, or evict based on Least Recently Used (LRU).

Typically, it is common to just "evict" entries when the data changes and only refresh the cache as needed, when the entry is next accessed, pulling it from the underlying data store (SOR) and storing it in the cache, as so...

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

  @Cacheable("PERSONS")
  Person findById(Long id);

  @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "PERSONS", key = "#result.id")
  Person save(Person person);
}
```

This caching strategy suggests that you should not cache the "search result(s)", where the number of results can be quite extensive over a given timeframe, especially in a highly concurrent context, but rather cache the records that actually get "used" (i.e. loaded, or accessed).

In addition, your application may break down if you were to later change you query methods to return a "projection" rather than the entire `Person` object, which might contain many other "references", though is somewhat dependent on your lazy loading strategy as well. Still, it is not uncommon to reduce the amount of data transferred by using projections (or DTOs) that is only necessary to satisfy the presentation of information.

Frankly, it is better to optimize your queries and apply the appropriate indexes than it is to try and store search results in memory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed thoughts. What I might add is that a "person" and "firstname, lastname" is just an example. My business usecase is much more complex and very specific, so I made a simple example everyone can understand. As moreover my question is independent of the target object...

Comment: I tried the approach `key = "#firstname + #lastname"`, but spring tells me: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1030E: The operator 'ADD' is not supported between objects of type 'null' and 'null'`. Of course I'm not trying to pass null values as parameters here, but why does Spring think they are null?

Comment: Perhaps because you have not compiled with debug mode on, which then would not include the parameter names in the byte code.  However, alternatively you can use the `#p<Number>` SpEL variable reference as you have done below.